# Make an existing Git branch connect to origin instead of upstream

Tags: git

I recently forked a project and stuck to an issue.

I have following remote:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Hesamedin/passenger-android.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Hesamedin/passenger-android.git (push)
upstream        git@github.com:mycompany/passenger-android.git (fetch)
upstream        git@github.com:mycompany/passenger-android.git (push)
```

I guess I used wrong command and connected my v2_dev barach to upstream. Now I want to connect it to origin instead. What is the command? Should I rebase it?

I'm in v2_dev local branch

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/v2_dev
  origin/gh-pages
  origin/master
  origin/mvn-repo
  upstream/v2_dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I did to fix my local problem is as:

```
$ git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Hesam/.ssh/id_rsa':
From github.com:Hesamedin/passenger-android
 * [new branch]      v2_dev     -> origin/v2_dev

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/v2_dev
  origin/gh-pages
  origin/master
  origin/mvn-repo
  origin/v2_dev
  upstream/v2_dev

$  git branch -u origin v2_dev
Branch v2_dev set up to track remote branch v2_dev from origin by rebasing.

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/v2_dev
  origin/gh-pages
  origin/master
  origin/mvn-repo
  origin/v2_dev
  upstream/v2_dev
```

I then merged upstream/v2_dev to origin/v2_dev and deleted upstream/v2_dev.

Seems everything is okay.